# Proving a theorem about $0-1$ sequences

Tags: analysis

I am trying to understand the 4 page long paper from Everett from 1977 called: [Iteration of the Number-Theoretic Function f(2n)=n, f(2n+1)=3n+2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870877900871/pdf?md5=af783c7f73780ecdca2d75beb3ff9df0&pid=1-s2.0-0001870877900871-main.pdf)

The authoer is considering the collatz function in his paper:

$$ f(m) = \begin{cases} m/2 & m \, even\\  (3m+1)/2 & m \, odd, \end{cases}$$

He states that every integer $m \geq 0$ gives rise to a sequence 
$$ m \to [m_0 , m_1 , m_2 ,\dot ] $$
where $m_0 = m$ and $m_n = f^n(m)$, for example
$$ 7 \to [7,11,17,26,13,20 ,.. ]$$

Then he states that each integer $m$ also induces a parity sequence

$$ m \to \{ x_0 ,x_1 ,x_2 ,\dots \} $$

with $$ x_n := m_n \mod  2$$, for example
$$ 7 \to \{ 1,1,1,0,1,0,...\}$$

**First Question** He states that it is trivial that
$$ m \to \{ 1,0,1,0,...\}$$ 
iff $m=1$. Why? I see that $m=1$ induces the sequence, but how do you see the converse?

---

He then formulate his first Theorem

> **Theorem 1** An arbitrary diadic sequence $ \{ x_0 , \dots , x_{N-1} \}$
>   arises in the above explained way, from a unique integer $m < 2^N$.
>   Specifically, the $x_n$ determine $m$ and $m_N$ to be of the forms 
>   $$m = a_{N-1} + 2^N Q_N : \quad 0 \leq a_{N-1} < 2^N$$ and
>   $$ m_N =b_{N-1} + 3^X Q_N : \quad 0 \leq b_{N-1} < 3^X, \, X= \sum_{0}^{N-1} x_n$$

To proof the theorem I guess it is sufficent to proof that for diadic sequence exits a corresponding integer $m < 2^N$. The uniquness follows because there are $2^N$ diadic sequences and only $2^N$ non-neagtive integers less then $2^N$.

**Second Question**
In the proof he shows by induction on $N$ that he $m$ and $m_N$ will be of that specific form. First, what is $Q_N$? He doesnt mention it anwhere.. I guess a non-negative integer? The $a_{N-1}$ must be unique. What is about the $b_{N-1}$?

For $N=1$ there are only two different diadic sequences, namly $\{ 0 \}$ and $\{ 1\}$ and its easy to verify the statement with $Q_1= 0$ for both $m=0$ and $m=1$.

In his indcution step he assume the statement is correct for $N$ and considers first the case where $b_{N-1}$ is even. He then argues:

> $x_N = 0$ implies $Q_N = 2 Q_{N+1}$

Why should that be the case?

Comment: Regarding the perceived mistake in the title: this is simply another way of stating the same definition. For even $m$ (i.e. $m=2n$) you get $f(m)=f(2n)=m/2=n$, and for odd $m$ (i.e. $m=2n+1$) you get $f(m)=f(2n+1)=(3m+1)/2=(6n+4)/2=3n+2$.

Comment: @KlausDraeger Ahh! I thought mb in 1977 they didnt even proof-read the title ^^. I will edit my question then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now - the statement is:

For any diadic sequence $\{ x_0 ,\dots, x_{N-1} \}$ exists a integer $m < 2^N$ that induces the sequence. Specifically, the $x_n$ determine $m$ and $m_N$ to be of the forms 
 $$m = a_{N-1} + 2^N l : \quad 0 \leq a_{N-1} < 2^N$$ and
 $$ m_N =b_{N-1} + 3^X l : \quad 0 \leq b_{N-1} < 3^X, \, X= \sum_{0}^{N-1} x_n$$

for **any** $l \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{ 0 \}$.

Then the proof makes actually sense.

**Induction Start**: If $x_0 = 0$ then $m= 2l$ induces the sequence for any $l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m= 2l +1 $ induces $x_0 =1 $ for any  $l \in \mathbb{N}$

**Induction Step** Given a sequence $\{ x_0 ,\dots ,x_{N-1},x_N\}$.
Then $$m = a_{N-1} + 2^N l$$ induces $$\{ x_0 ,\dots ,x_{N-1} \}$$ and $m_N =b_{N-1} + 3^X l$. Now if $l$ is even and if $b_{N-1}$ is even, then $m_{N}$ is even and thus $x_N =0$ thus the sequence will be indcued by any $m$ of the form  $$m = a_{N-1} + 2^{N+1} l$$ with $l\in\mathbb{N}. And then one has to check the other cases.